# Javascript - Mantener visible a un div con LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Hice un agregado funcional a un script, y no puedo (no sé hacerlo, la verdad), **agregarle un LocalStorage al siguiente script** para mantener al div #regalo visible cuando recargo la página.

El div #regalo es visible sólo cuando el valor del input #total está entre 999 y 2999, pero aunque el script original ya tiene su propio LocalStorage para otras funciones, **no puedo mantener visible al div #regalo después de una recarga**.

La función está presente, ok, pero el div desaparece de la pantalla...

¿Cómo agrego LocalStorage al siguiente script para **mantener visible a #regalo** si recargo la página...?

**SCRIPT:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  function manageRegalo() {
    const total = Number($("#total").val().replace(".",""));

    if(total > 999 && total < 2999) {
      $('#regalo').show();
    }
    else{
      $('#regalo').hide();
    }
  }

  $(document).on('click', function (event) {
      const target = event.target;
      if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.bbp')) {
        manageRegalo();
      }
    });
  manageRegalo();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías guardar el valor de #total en tu `localStorage`, para después usarlo en tu función, así al recargar la pagina, le asignara el valor de `totalStorage` a total.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      function manageRegalo() {
        //Cachas el valor de tu storage
        var totalStorage = Number(localStorage.getItem("total"));
        var total = Number($("#total").val().replace(".",""));
        if(totalStorage != null && total === 0) {
        /*Si hay valor en el Storage y el input de captura viene vacio,
          entonces le asigna totalStorage a total*/
            total = totalStorage;
        }

        if(total > 999 && total < 2999) {
          $('#regalo').show();
        }
        else{
          $('#regalo').hide();
        }
      }

      $(document).on('click', function (event) {
          const target = event.target;
          if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.bbp')) {
            manageRegalo();
            //Cuando haces click en tu elemento, guarda el #total en el storage
            localStorage.setItem('total', Number($("#total").val().replace(".","")));
          }
        });
      manageRegalo();
    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias **Ricardo**. Funciona de maravillas. Testado en todos los browser, escritorio y móvil. Muchas gracias!... +10 ...

Answer (score 1):

Mira ver si asi puedes solucionar tu pregunta:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function manageRegalo() {
  const total = Number($("#total").val().replace(".",""));
  //Si esta en el intervalo o esta en localStorage almacenado con la clave "mostrar"
  if(total > 999 && total < 2999 || !!localStorage.getItem('mostrar')) {
    $('#regalo').show();
    //Si aun no esta almacenado en localStorage lo guardo
    if(!!localStorage.getItem('mostrar') === false) {
        localStorage.setItem('mostrar', true)
    }
  }
  else{
    $('#regalo').hide();
  }
}

$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.bbp')) {
      manageRegalo();
    }
});

manageRegalo();
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias **Daniel**. Algo pasa, que con tu script el div `#regalo` se queda persistente en pantalla aunque limpie toda la caché y borre todos los datos de los navegadores (el script no tira errores en ningún inspector). De todas formas el usuario **@Ricardo** publicó una respuesta que sí me funciona, y veo que es algo diferente a la tuya. Vale, estoy aprendiendo desde cero, y me cuesta asimilar algunos conceptos. Muchas gracias...